# Cypress problems searching for data within a container

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using the latest version of Cypress (4.12.0). I'm having trouble finding a checkbox in an element that I selected on a previous step.

Here is my Cypress JS code:

```
const itemContainer: any = cy.get(`div .line-item:eq(0)`);                        // <<<<<<< LINE #1 >>>>>>>>>>>>
// TODO - can't get the following to work, seems like it's not using the container
itemContainer.get('input:eq(0)').should('have.property', 'type', 'checkbox');     // <<<<<<< LINE #2 >>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Here is the generated HTML from Chrome Dev tools:

```
<div class="product-details card-item">
    <div class="card-container line-item"><input name="selectItem" type="checkbox">
        <div class="left-half"><img alt="product"
                                    src="xxx">
            <div class="card-info">
                Some data here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the error from the Cypress test run:

```
get div .line-item:eq(0)
get input:eq(0)
assert
expected <input#select-all-items> to have property type
```

In my Cypress code, LINE #1 is definitely working as expected, because when I pin that entry in the Cypress UI, the `<div.line-item>` element is highlighted. But when LINE #2 runs, it is looking for an element that is outside and way before the element that should be in the `itemContainer` in the code. The `<input#select-all-items>` element is not even an ancestor of the `<div.line-item>` element. It seems as if the `itemContainer.get()` in my test code is starting at the root, and not the element that Cypress selected in the preceding statement.

Not sure if this really matters, but we're using React to generate the HTML.

Comment: ***seems like it's not using the container*** - correct, see [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Requirements). Try using `.find()` instead.

Comment: On an input, `type` is an attribute not a property - try `.should('have.attr', 'type', 'checkbox')`.

Comment: Thanks @eric99, both of those fixes worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Cypress runs asynchronously (i.e., you cannot rely on the execution order of the variable assignment is before LINE #2), try using [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#Syntax) instead of creating variables:

```
cy.get('div .line-item:eq(0)').as('itemContainer');
cy.get('@itemContainer').get('input:eq(0)').should('...');
```